# Error: Node is detached from document at ElementHandle._scrollIntoViewIfNeeded?

Tags: node.js, test-automation

Я через pupeeter делаю атомтизацию. Вот:

```js
await loginPage.waitForNavigation('networkidle2')

await loginPage.waitForTimeout(1000)

await loginPage.waitForXPath('//*[@id="KmsiCheckboxField"]')

loginButton = await loginPage.$x('//*[@id="KmsiCheckboxField"]', )

await loginButton[0].click()

await loginPage.waitForXPath('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')

loginButton = await loginPage.$x('//*[@id="idSIButton9"]')

await loginButton[0].click()

await loginPage.waitForNavigation('networkidle0')



//await loginPage.waitForTimeout(60000)



//const continueButton = await loginPage.$x('//*[@id="page-content-wrapper"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button')

//console.log(continueButton)

//if (continueButton[0]) {

//    console.log("Зашли в условие")

//    await continueButton[0].click()

//}



await loginPage.waitForTimeout(1000)

await console.log('Hi')

await loginPage.waitForSelector(`div[data-tid="team-${nameOfchannel}"]`)

loginButton = await loginPage.$$(`div[data-tid="team-${nameOfchannel}"]`)

await loginButton[0].click()
```

Если  закоментировать кусочек кода выше то все работает. А если нет то вылетит вот это.

```
Error: Node is detached from document 

    at ElementHandle._scrollIntoViewIfNeeded (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\node.js\Class atternder\headlessService\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\JSHandle.js:317:19) 

    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>) 

    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) 

    at async ElementHandle.click (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\node.js\Class atternder\headlessService\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\JSHandle.js:389:9) 

    at async Object.joinConf (C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\node.js\Class atternder\headlessService\controllers\microsoftTeamsBotExport.js:117:13) 

    at async C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\node.js\Class atternder\headlessService\index.js:69:13 

{
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: А если заменить `await continueButton[0].click()` на `await page.evaluate((element) => { element.click(); }, continueButton[0])`, что-то изменится?

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, нет.  Но также я понял что если убрать await loginPage.waitForTimeout(60000) то все заработает. Но теперь незнаю как поставить здаержку.